# Converting shell script to Objective-C CLI

Tags: objective-c, command-line, shell, nstask, command-line-tool

I am planning to convert a rather long shell script I have into an Objective C command line tool. I'm planning to use NSTask to run the shell commands (this is a large script, and it has several thousand copy/move/delete operations). My question is, will continually allocating and deallocating NSTask objects to run all these commands result in a large performance hit?

Is there a better way to do it than using NSTask?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It's a little difficult to see point of converting a shell script to an Objective-C program, so it's hard to say what the best way is to go about it.

Comment: The main reason is that I want to protect my shell script from being opened and read like an open book by the user (especially since this is a shareware app). Just need a way to protect the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just moving/copying/deleting files, have you considered using [`NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: I forgot to mention also that I need to set permissions on files. Is that possible with NSFileManager?

Comment: Assuming the CLI is running with the perms to do so, then yes. It's in `-[NSFileManager setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:]`.